# Cannot rebuild containers: base name (${BUILD_IMAGE}) should not be blank

Tags: docker

Lately whenever I run `docker compose build` I see this, and then the command ends:

```
Step 1/21 : ARG BASE_IMAGE
Step 2/21 : ARG BUILD_IMAGE
Step 3/21 : FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS prep
 ---> eb59a6673fd3
Step 4/21 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 947bba5183b9
Step 5/21 : COPY *.sln nuget.config Directory.Build.targets Packages.props \nuget\
Step 1/21 : ARG BASE_IMAGE
Step 2/21 : ARG BUILD_IMAGE
Step 3/21 : FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS prep
base name (${BUILD_IMAGE}) should not be blank
```

My main `Dockerfile` starts with this:

```
# escape=`

ARG BASE_IMAGE
ARG BUILD_IMAGE

FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS prep
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Gather only artifacts necessary for NuGet restore, retaining directory structure
COPY *.sln nuget.config Directory.Build.targets Packages.props \nuget\
COPY src\ \temp\
RUN Invoke-Expression 'robocopy C:\temp C:\nuget\src /s /ndl /njh /njs *.csproj *.scproj packages.config'

FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS builder
```

Presumably the error is specifically referring to the last line: `FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS builder`. However, this file was never modified, so it must be some other issue.

My `docker-compose.yml` has this, which is the only reference to `BUILD_IMAGE` in my solution:

```
  solution:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-solution:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${SOLUTION_BASE_IMAGE}
        BUILD_IMAGE: ${SOLUTION_BUILD_IMAGE}
        BUILD_CONFIGURATION: ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION}
    scale: 0
```

And `SOLUTION_BASE_IMAGE` is defined in my `.env` as `SOLUTION_BUILD_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8`

What I have tried:

- `docker system prune`
- Restarting Docker
- Updating Docker to latest version
- Restarting PC
- Running everything as an admin

Comment: The docker file seems to be running a second time in parallel. It doesnt get to step 6 (copy src...), but starting again. Then failing on step 3. Can you share full docker-compose.yml file? Also is there defo no docker-compose-override.yml or .env.custom files?

Comment: Also, what happens if you hard code the BUILD_IMAGE into the dockerfile? (Ie replace variable with value from .env)